# How can i set visible="true" attribute to the Panel from other component?

Tags: apache-flex

My code is :

< mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"     xmlns:rest="com.sourcestream.flex.http.*"

    xmlns:custom="Components.*" initialize="loadProduct()" 
     >

```
   <mx:Panel id="main"   >

   </mx:Panel>

  <mx:Panel id="addressId" visible="false"  >

      <custom:AddressForm  >

      </custom:AddressForm>


 </mx:Panel>
```

my code for AddressForm is in another .mxml file

< ? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

< mx:Form    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="400" height="300"  verticalScrollPolicy="off">

< mx:Button label="Back" id="back" click="goBack(event)"/>

< /mx:Form>

on goBack() event i want to disable the Panel having id="main"

plese tell me the solution ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function goBack(e:Event):void{
    e.currentTarget.parent.parent.visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add an id to the custom component like this,

```
<custom:AddressForm  id="myCustomComponent">

  </custom:AddressForm>
```

and access the control whose visibility can be set,

```
public function goBack(e:Event):void{
    myCustomComponent.main.visible = false;
}
```